# When I boot-up I get this dialog: "Backup Failed: Failed with an unknown error"

Tags: backup, startup, deja-dup

---

**Backup Failed**
*Failed with an unknown error*.

---

When I booted-up this morning I got a dialog which presented the above message and **no other information**!

The dialog is "helpful" in that it tells me something is wrong, but I have no idea what it is referring to; so it isn't actually helpful.

What might be causing this "backup" error when I am **starting** the system?

I've restarted several times and keep getting the same message.

I checked the disks using *System--Administration--Disk Utility* via a **Live-CD**, and it reported **no errors**.

---

I've just now noticed one tell-tale sign which is probably significant, but I don't know how to interpret it...

My normal routine, with two of my drives (single partition per drive) is to **manually** mount them (via Nautilus)...  However, what I've just noticed is that one of them is showing as **already mounted** at startup, which has **not** been the case prior to today...

I haven't got the hang of this mounting "stuff" yet.... but this seems to be a relevant point...

Comment: @fred.bear this is your second post that is "putting out a fire" even though none exists...calm down.  first OMG over terminal versus virtual terminal and now this

Comment: @ aking1012: I'm afraid i find your comment oddly cryptic. I can't see  how it helps me to resolve the issue of a **Warning** dialog which keeps appearing each and every time I boot up..  Perhaps you could expound on it a bit.  You may not see "fire" but I see it every time I start my computer.

Comment: @aking1012 what in the world could possibly be wrong with either this Question or his prior one about virtual terminals? This one is exactly the sort of question this site was made for, the other one was incredibly interesting and valuable. *»Surely you're joking«*

Comment: Looks like the error comes from Deja Dup.

Comment: @aking, he's asked a perfectly reasonable question about what appears to be a failing backup... if you want to tear people to shreds, go hang out in the old-fashioned forums, this is a place to help people with their problems.

Comment: @jeremy :) Thanks...  I do use Deja Dup (as you seem to already realize).. I'll try uninstalling it, and re-installing it... and see what effect that has

Comment: @jeremy: All is well, once again (no Warning message)...  I've purged and banished Deja Dup (I didn't like it anyhow. I prefer "Lucky Backup")... so it would be great if you could present an answer about it and I can then mark your answer as **accepted**..  Thanks...

Comment: PS. Before I purged Deja Dup, if first only **uninstalled** it... Things workd normally on the next reboot... I then **reinstalled** it and the Warning message was back again...  Perhaps a purge and reinstall would clear up the problem, but I've gone for anothe backup app (as mentioned above)

Comment: It isn't the question itself that I was objecting to...it's the tone...every question is an OMG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error appears, after some googling, to be with **Deja Dup**. As you've already solved it, I'll keep this short, but the solution was as follows (from comments):

All is well, once again (no Warning message)... I've purged and banished Deja Dup (I didn't like it anyhow. I prefer "Lucky Backup") -- fred.bear

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I resolved it by directing my backup to a new directory and doing a full backup. I did this because on a day earlier in the week I was unable to restore a directory and found a corrupt backup in the backup directory.